# Contains for strings not working in powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, powershell-2.0

I ran the following very simple command in powershell. However it does not seem to be working:

```
If("2f7c654f-16ce-46d8-a037-9827916ba655_opt.script" -contains "2f7c654f-16ce-46d8-a037-9827916"){"hi"}
```

Can someone please guide me as to where am I going wrong

Answer (score 2):

the `-contains` operator is an *array* operator, not a string operator. it tests for an exact match with one or more items in an array. that is a *really* common mistake. [*grin*]

you want the `.Contains()` string method.

Comment: or -like with wildcards

Comment: @OwainEsau - yep ... but the OP had a very direct problem with the two `contains` versions, so that is all i mentioned. i am always uncertain how much extra info to give ...